# ERROR TypeError: _co.onClk is not a function angular6

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, typescript

Working on angular 6 with html and type script , when i try to execute this, response showing some error .

Error:-

```
MyCompComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: _co.onClk is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (MyCompComponent.html:5)
    at handleEvent (core.js:9947)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11040)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:10743)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7406)
    at core.js:7850
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:1140)
    at ZoneDelegate.push.../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3645)
    at ZoneDelegate.push.../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
```

This is my my-comp.component.html

```
<p>
  my-comp works!
</p>
<h2>Customer Information</h2>
<button type="button" (click)="onClk($event)">Make Request</button>
<div *ngIf="loading">loading...</div>
<pre>Data Obtained is: {{ data | json }}</pre>
```

I am adding my type script my-comp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'myorg-my-comp',
  templateUrl: './my-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-comp.component.css']
})
export class component {
   // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
   data: Object;
   loading: boolean;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
  // this.makeRequest();
  }  

  onClk(event){

    this.loading = true;
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8090/REST/v2/public/customer/100').
    subscribe(res => {
      console.log('recived:res',res);
      this.data = res;
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }


}
```

I checked and  [I tried this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298473/error-typeerror-co-onclk-is-not-a-function)   , but still i am getting same problem, can any one suggest on this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `export class MyCompComponent`?

Comment: It should work. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You will have problems with onClk any way since it's not bound.

Comment: what is the instruction "debugger;" that you has in your code?

Comment: HI Eliseo, that is just for debugging purpose, any way i removed it..can you please provide your inputs.

Comment: HI barbsan, i didn't export the MyCompcomponent , Can you please provide your inputs.

Comment: @kanchetime do you have more components in your app (especially with class named `component`)? Your code should work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9ftvk

Comment: Thank you  Barbsan , Yes two  components(1.component.ts,2.my-comp.component.ts) are there, I checked you link, hello world is working for me also , but while calling endpoint only getting problems. Waiting for your inputs.